# Compose two components into a single process in python

Tags: ros, ros2, nodelet, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Composition/) describes how to do this in C++. How do I do the same in python?

My attempt so far:

```
class NodeletA(Node):            
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('nodelet_a')

class NodeletB(Node):            
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('nodelet_b')

def main():   

    rclpy.init(args=None)
    executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()

    a = NodeletA()
    executor.add_node(a)
    
    b = NodeletB()
    executor.add_node(b)

    executor.spin()
    
    a.destroy_node()
    b.destroy_node()

    rclpy.shutdown()
```

This creates the components, but the `spin` method does not block like the `rclpy.spin()` does. The program instantly destroys the nodes and shuts down. how do I make `executor.spin()` blocking. The executor needs to be multithreaded because one of my nodes hosts an action server, and I need the `execute_callback` of the action to be non-blocking.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351442/compose-two-components-into-a-single-process-in-python/) by [CraigH92](https://answers.ros.org/users/54432/craigh92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2020-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-05**:
Not sure whether it just hasn't been updated, but at least according to [ROS 2: Features Status](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Features/#features-status) node composition is a C++-only feature.

**Comment by [CraigH92](https://answers.ros.org/users/54432/craigh92/) on 2020-05-05**:
This was a red herring, sorry. The above code works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a red herring, sorry. The above code works.

The problem was my `NodeletB` was creating a client using an IDL type that was an action, not a service, and this caused it to crash without any error messages.

---

Originally posted by [CraigH92](https://answers.ros.org/users/54432/craigh92/) with karma: 128 on 2020-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0